# Unable to limit maximum session on WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: session, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 5.10.0 running in the official Docker image and followed the guide [here](https://medium.com/swlh/limiting-multiple-active-user-session-in-wso2-identity-server-89e93fcf826e) to setup session limiting for users with defined roles. I have attempted to use the main way described in the article (using the active-session-limit-handler), as well as the alternative method described in section 2 (using adaptive authentication Javascript functions). Neither method has worked for me.

Through error logs I was able to trace the issue back to the following query:

```
SELECT USER_ID FROM IDN_AUTH_USER WHERE USER_NAME =? AND TENANT_ID =? AND DOMAIN_NAME =?
```

This query is returning no results, which causes the JS function to fail/believe there are no active sessions for the user.

I assumed this was possibly because I wasn't explicitly turning on session persistence, so I [followed the docs](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/authentication-session-persistence/) and modified my deployment.toml to persist sessions. After restarting WSO2 IS with the modified deployment.toml I am still failing in the same way. The query returns no results even if the user has multiple active sessions.

How do I enable limiting the maximum number of sessions?

Answer (score 2):

There is an already reported issue[[1]](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/9396) as limiting active user sessions feature is not working as expected in the IS-5.10.0 GA pack. It has been fixed in the 5.10 WUM updated pack and the latest release of IS-5.11.0. You can switch to the latest version or otherwise, you can apply a patch with the [fix](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-local-auth-basicauth/pull/77).

Comment: Thanks, I've upgraded to the latests (5.11.0) and tried this again. It is at least not throwing a 500 now, but it gives me the error `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://HOST:9443/api/identity/auth/v1.1/context/916aff37-aaf8-464c-bede-7f249279ff1a`. This happens when I do have too many active sessions and I attempt to either terminate them or deny the current login attempt.