# Unable to terminate WSO2 IS sessions

Tags: session, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I previously had issues with WSO2 IS active-sessions-limit-handler not working. It was resolved by a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151603/unable-to-limit-maximum-session-on-wso2-identity-server) I asked (I upgraded to 5.11.0).

Now the issue is that when I follow [this guide](https://medium.com/swlh/limiting-multiple-active-user-session-in-wso2-identity-server-89e93fcf826e) and setup an active-sessions-limit-handler for an SP, the server knows when I exceed the limit, but it is not able to deal with the situation correctly.

I have the max number of sessions set to 2, so when I try and login with the same user for a third time WSO2 correctly knows it is now over the limit. The issue is it gives me the following screen:
[image: wso2 session error]

When I select any of the 3 presented options, I get an Authentication Error and the login fails. If I go to the My Account page for the user I can see that the sessions are active that are expected to be.

It seems like WSO2 is unable to retrieve the active sessions. When this error happens, I also see the following error log which appears to be that WSO2 is making a call to it's own API that is being rejected as unauthorized:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://HOST:9443/api/identity/auth/v1.1/context/916aff37-aaf8-464c-bede-7f249279ff1a
```

Do I need to configure anything differently for the API to not return a 401? I haven't been able to find any open issues that seem to be the same problem.

EDIT, adding full stacktrace:

```
[2020-12-16 17:49:00,105] [4e6a703b-f19a-4d27-a80e-c2f2088f7d0e]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.model.graph.js.JsLogger} - USER Has one of Roles: [admin]
[2020-12-16 17:49:00,334] [2192ca86-fc09-4767-9647-ff8ec91a6698] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.AuthContextAPIClient} - Sending GET request to URL : https://HOST:9443/api/identity/auth/v1.1/context/1bef7d0a-5aba-4e14-a7a3-a6bb53e02a62, failed. java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://HOST:9443/api/identity/auth/v1.1/context/1bef7d0a-5aba-4e14-a7a3-a6bb53e02a62
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1924)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.AuthContextAPIClient.getContextProperties(AuthContextAPIClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.jsp.handle_002dmultiple_002dsessions_jsp._jspService(handle_002dmultiple_002dsessions_jsp.java:256)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthenticationEndpointFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationEndpointFilter.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:98)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Seems the retrieving active sessions is failing. Actually "You currently have 2 active session(s). You are not allowed to have more than 2 active session(s)." should be the message on your screen and active sessions should be listed. Can you attach the full stack trace for the error?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna I added the stacktrace to the original post. But yes, I agree that it's unable to get the active sessions, even though it knows they exist

Comment: @wearbob Is your WSO2 IS deployment fronted by a load balancer?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna not explicitly. But it is running on a GCP instance which may internally use some load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the scenario by uncommenting the `<context-param>` block with the name `AuthenticationRESTEndpointURL` in `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint/WEB-INF/web.xml` file.

````
    <!-- *************** Authentication REST API URL Configuration ********************** -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>AuthenticationRESTEndpointURL</param-name>
        <param-value>https://localhost:9443/api/identity/auth/v1.1/</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- *************** End of Authentication REST API URL Configuration ********************** -->```
````

Comment: It makes the call to localhost now, but fails due to an SSL error:
`[f40628e0-4370-4873-a8bc-0156964739ab] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.AuthContextAPIClient} - Sending GET request to URL : https://localhost:9443/api/identity/auth/v1.1/c
ontext/55f6aa52-0394-41db-9e87-9f0062fd3a3f, failed. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching localhost found.`

Comment: Can you try the first option here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/65320529/10055162)? add the SAN to the cert

Comment: @ Anuradha Karunarathna Sorry for the slow response. I've been trying to get a cert with a localhost SAN, but my IT department is having trouble giving me one issued from our CA. They say it is invalid to have localhost as the domain. Is there another direction I can go, possibly fixing the 401 returned when calling HOST?